# Optional Radio button and text box after user selects a option in the dropdown list

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to create a dropdown list with various options. 
When I select the option "Newspaper", I want radio button options to appear for me to choose a newspaper title.
When I select the option "Referred by Employee", I want a textbox with aplaceholder of "Employee name, ID, workplace" to appear.
When I select the option "Others", I want a textbox with no placeholder to appear.

This is what I have so far (edited the code):

```
<script>
function checkvalue(val)
{
    if(val=="newspaper")
       document.getElementById('job1').style.display='block';
    else if(val=="referral")
       document.getElementById('job2').style.display='block';
    else if(val=="others")
       document.getElementById('job3').style.display='block';
    else
       document.getElementById('job').style.display='none'; 
}
</script>

<select name="job" onchange='checkvalue(this.value)'> 
    <option>pick a option</option>  
    <option value="website">Website</option>
    <option value="postfly">Poster/Flyers</option>
    <option value="newspaper">Newspaper</option>
    <option value="referral">Referred by Employee</option>
    <option value="others">Others</option>
</select>

<div id="job1" name="job" style="display:block">
  <label><input type="radio" name="newspaperradio" id="yesid" value="Paper1"> Paper 1 </label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="newspaperradio" id="noid" value="Paper2"> Paper 2 </label>
</div>

<div id="job2" name="job" style="display:block">
<label for="referral">fdr:</label>
<input type="text" name="referral" id="referral" value="" placeholder="employee name, id, workplace" siez="45px"/>
</div>

<div id="job3" name="job" style="display:block">
<label for="others">fd:</label>
<input type="text" name="others" id="others" value="" placeholder="provide more details"/>
</div>
```

Comment: So add the HTML for the radio buttons and so forth, hide them with CSS, and then use JS to show them at the appropriate moment. (Where you have groups of elements that hide or show together, put them in a containing div and just hide/show the div.)

Comment: I don't know how because when I want to add another textbox, I have to use the same id and name from the first label

Comment: What do you mean you *have to* use the same id?That doesn't make sense, it defeats the purpose of having an id. Anyway, a starting place for you would be to add HTML for all of the controls you need, then from there look at how to hide the ones that need to be displayed dynamically.

Comment: Where is the HTML for radio buttons? So you want to re-use the label and input text (excluding the radio buttons) based on dropdown selection?

Comment: I have edited the code.

Comment: Make a js `switch` instead of if-else statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```js
function checkvalue(val) {
  //Hide all jobs
  var jobs = document.querySelectorAll("#job1, #job2, #job3");
  [].forEach.call(jobs, function (job){
 job.style.display = 'none';
  })

  if (val === "newspaper")
 document.getElementById('job1').style.display = 'block';
  else if (val === "referral")
 document.getElementById('job2').style.display = 'block';
  else if (val === "others")
 document.getElementById('job3').style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<select name="job" onchange='checkvalue(this.value)'> 
  <option>pick a option</option>  
  <option value="website">Website</option>
  <option value="postfly">Poster/Flyers</option>
  <option value="newspaper">Newspaper</option>
  <option value="referral">Referred by Employee</option>
  <option value="others">Others</option>
</select>

<div id="job1" name="job" style="display:none;">
 <label><input type="radio" name="newspaperradio" id="yesid" value="Paper1"> Paper 1 </label>
 <label><input type="radio" name="newspaperradio" id="noid" value="Paper2"> Paper 2 </label>
</div>

<div id="job2" name="job" style="display:none;">
 <label for="referral">fdr:</label>
 <input type="text" name="referral" id="referral" value="" placeholder="employee name, id, workplace" siez="45px" />
</div>

<div id="job3" name="job" style="display:none;">
 <label for="others">fd:</label>
 <input type="text" name="others" id="others" value="" placeholder="provide more details" />
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Phani Kumar M, 
I have a question regarding the code. 
If I want to have another dropdown list with the same options and optional textboxes, how would I go about doing it?